# SASS/CSS ~ Background: URL(); is not working

Tags: html, css, url, sass, background

[image]I have tried everything and this is super frustrating.  I can't add any images using CSS???  I am using background: url...  before you say (needs linked to a folder, use a /, use a ./). I have tried everything.  It does not work.  I am doing the "Battleship Project" from headfirst Javascript.  I've even tried to copy this code snippet from the finished folder they've supplied and there code isn't working either.  I am using VS Code.

//Just the problem portion I cut out for you ~ HTML

```
<div id="board">
      <!-- <img src="board.jpg" alt="" /> -->
      <div id="messageArea">hello world</div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td id="00"></td>
          <td id="01"></td>
          <td id="02"></td>
          <td id="03"></td>
          <td id="04"></td>
          <td id="05"></td>
          <td id="06"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="10"></td>
          <td id="11"></td>
          <td id="12"></td>
          <td id="13"></td>
          <td id="14" class="hit"></td>
          <td id="15"></td>
          <td id="16"></td>
        </tr>
```

//SCSS, but CSS is linked to my html

```
$greenBG: rgb(83, 175, 19);
$formBgColor: rgb(152, 207, 113);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

#board {
  position: relative;
  width: 1024px;
  height: 863px;
  margin: auto;
  background: url("board.jpg");
  #messageArea {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 0;
    color: $greenBG;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
}
```

You can review to full finished code supplied by Headfirst at https://www.wickedlysmart.com/hfjs/

its Chapter 8 folder

Thank you all so much

Comment: What is the file structure of your files? I used a web image and it worked. I imagine it's the file path that's incorrect

Comment: my image is in the folder so I have tried the following: Background: url("/board.jpg");          Background: url("./board.jpg");              Background: url("board.jpg");  none of them work

Comment: show us your folders and where the image and css file are.

Comment: okay, I added a picture.

Comment: it works if my styles are in my HTML head but not to an external css file.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

a web image works here like this!

the problem absolutly is with your file direction.

```css
#board{
background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQZM2.png');
}
```

```html
<div id="board">
      <!-- <img src="board.jpg" alt="" /> -->
      <div id="messageArea">hello world</div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td id="00"></td>
          <td id="01"></td>
          <td id="02"></td>
          <td id="03"></td>
          <td id="04"></td>
          <td id="05"></td>
          <td id="06"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="10"></td>
          <td id="11"></td>
          <td id="12"></td>
          <td id="13"></td>
          <td id="14" class="hit"></td>
          <td id="15"></td>
          <td id="16"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: my image is in my project folder not a website.  Could that be my problem?

Comment: try Background: url("/(folder name)/board.jpg");

Comment: it's not in a folder anymore.  Just in my project

Comment: so you should use background: url("board.jpg") like you said you have tried!

Comment: did u try background: url("./board.jpg") @JoshWenner

Comment: both url("board.jpg") and url("./board.jpg") work for me